# Добавить класс в пункт меню drupal 7

Tags: drupal, php, html, css

Нужно вставить в некоторые теги li главного меню класс separate. Типа:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li class="separate"><a href="">About</a></li>
<li class="separate"><a href="">contact</a></li>
<li class="separate"><a href="">help</a></li>
</ul>
```

Как это сделать на drupal7?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.fl.ru/commune/professionalnyie/322/drupal/2488526/izmenenie-klassa-ul-v-menyu.html

```
function themename_menu_link__main_menu(array $variables) {
 $element = $variables['element'];
 $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);

return '<li class="separate">' . $output . "</li>\n";
```

}